# Merge [marko] and [markojs]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I've just discovered tags [marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marko) and [markojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markojs), both referring to the same [marko ui library](https://github.com/marko-js/marko).

I'd suggest to merge [markojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markojs) into tag [marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marko), or at least make it a synonymous for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a reasonable suggestion. There were only 3 questions tagged [markojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markojs) that did not have the [marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marko) tag, and they clearly all referred to the same library.

So, this is now done:

[marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marko) ← [markojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markojs)

with the master tag being the actual name of the library.

Should be live in a few moments, after accounting for caching effects.